# Cannot set combobox selected item opening a view

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, template10

I created a new project using template10 and I'm working to a simple form: I load a list of items from a remote server in a comboxbox and select one of the items  after the list is loaded.
I tried setting **SelectedValue**, **SelectedItem** ot **SelectedIndex**, but when the Form is shown the listbox appears unselected.
Am I missing something?

this is the xaml

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="voceSpesaCb" Margin="16,16,0,0" 
            RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="parameterResizer"
            RelativePanel.Below="voceSpesaTextBlock"
            DisplayMemberPath="Descrizione"
            SelectedValue="{x:Bind ViewModel.VoceCorrente, Converter={StaticResource XConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Voci, Converter={StaticResource XConverter}}"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

this is the code

```
        Voci = await vociSpesaTable.OrderBy(vs => vs.Descrizione).ToListAsync();
        VoceCorrente = Voci.FirstOrDefault(vs => vs.VoceSpesaNo == Item.VoceSpesaNo);
```

in the setter of the properties there is the call to the RaisePropertyChanged

Comment: Show the code you are using. If you want to select a specific value, each of those should work (provided you have the right code to select using the method chosen)

Answer (score 1):

Looks loike I found the problem. For reasons I don't understand at full I have to set Mode=TwoWay for the ItemsSource property too.

```
            <ComboBox x:Name="voceSpesaCb" Margin="16,16,0,0" 
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWith="parameterResizer"
                RelativePanel.Below="voceSpesaTextBlock"
                DisplayMemberPath="Descrizione"
                SelectedValue="{x:Bind ViewModel.VoceCorrente, Converter={StaticResource XConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Voci, Converter={StaticResource XConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      />
```

This way it works

Comment: There are 3 binding modes. `OneTime` will read the view-model when the XAML is initialized, which is very high-performance but if your view-model data has not yet loaded, it can be a problem. `OneWay` will read the view-model when initialized and will setup the events to listen for view-model changes. Neither will write to the view-model. `TwoWay` will act like `OneWay` PLUS when the value in XAML changes it will write back to the updated value to the view-model property setter. `TwoWay` is the only way to update your view-model. http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/xaml-binding-basics-101.html